# Patterns to avoid cloning around async block

Tags: asynchronous, rust, clone

I’m just wondering whether there are better, more idiomatic ways of cloning parameters prior to them being moved into async blocks?

For example in the following code:

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(32);
    let tx2 = tx.clone();

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        tx.send("sending from first handle").await;
    });

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        tx2.send("sending from second handle").await;
    });

    while let Some(message) = rx.recv().await {
        println!("GOT = {}", message);
    }
}
```

In this case it’s just tx2 but if there are multiple spawns with multiple parameters the cloning starts to get excessive.

Sometimes I guess a for loop/iterator can be used to avoid duplication, but was wondering whether there are other patterns people employ, perhaps capturing multiple params in a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not always more idiomatic, but you can clone next to the `async` block and use the same name (the same works with closures, by the way):

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(32);

    tokio::spawn({
        let tx = tx.clone();
        async move {
            tx.send("sending from first handle").await;
        }
    });

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        tx.send("sending from second handle").await;
    });

    while let Some(message) = rx.recv().await {
        println!("GOT = {}", message);
    }
}
```